# Laravel auth::check is true in controller, but in the blade is null

Tags: laravel, authentication

```
// controller
    public function handleCustomerData(Request $request, Customer $customer)
        {
            $location = $request->location;
            $phone = $request->phone;
            $project_name = $request->project_name;
    
            $id = $customer->insertGetId(["location" => $location, "phone" => $phone, "project_name" => 
            $project_name]);
            Auth::loginUsingId($id);
            //Cache::put("checkIn", true, now()->addMinutes(30));
            return response()->json(['success' => true, "id" => $id, "check" => Auth::check()]);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: you have to refresh page after Auth::loginUsingId($id);
            //Cache::put("checkIn", true, now()->addMinutes(30));
            return response()->json(['success' => true, "id" => $id, "check" => Auth::check()]);

Comment: thanks, but it's not work

Comment: show your js code

Comment: function submitData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/api/customer',
            data: customer,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.success) {
                    $(".select_make").addClass("none")
                }
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, hard to read/understand. Instead, please [edit] your question and paste all relevant information there. Thanks

Comment: if (res.success) {location.reload();}

Comment: dose my answer satisfy you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass every thing you want from controller to view with variables :

```
return view("your blade view",["user" => Auth::user()]);
```

and get it in blade like:

```
{{$user}}
```